# Open sets in normal spaces

Tags: general-topology

My question is related to a doubt about a proof of Urysohn's lemma. Suppose that $X$ is a normal, $T_1$-space. Can we find a basis for $X$ consisting of sets $U$ such that $V\subseteq \overline{V}\subseteq U$ for some open set $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in a regular space $X$ we can do this for any open set: in such a space we have that if $x \in U$ and $U$ open, there is some open subset $V$ such that $x \in V \subseteq \overline{V} \subseteq {U}$ This is a reformulation of regularity, in fact. To see this, note that $F = X \setminus U$ is closed and $x \notin F$, so by regularity there are disjoint open sets $ U_x \ni x$ and $W \supseteq F$. So $U_x \subseteq X\setminus W \subseteq X \setminus F = U$, and as $X \setminus W$ is closed, so we can replace $U_x$ by its closure in this inclusion, and use $U_x$ as our $V$.

So any open base has this property.